# Side Bar Navigation stops working after clicking some links on the Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [this side navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/hxjmxh4v/). On that same page, i have a form which gets displayed when i click a link, my problem now is it works only when i click on its link only, if i click a different navigation link  and then try to click on it to toggle the form its not working and so are other navigation links.

i have tried `$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();` this is the JQuery code i use to toggle the form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".ps").click(function(){
         if($("#div_data").is(":visible")){
           $("#div_data").hide();
        } else {
           $("#div_data").show();
        }
        return false;
     });
});
```

How can i make sure the the navigation works properly regardless of the link i have clicked, and that the form displays even after clicking other navigation links?

Comment: the click event is applied on `$(".ps")` only. that's why `it works only when i click on its link only`. You gotta apply the click event to other related element as well.

Comment: yes i want the form to toggle the form when i click on that link, the problem now is, when i click a different link and go back to it, it does not toggle the form.

Comment: does `#div_data` still exists after you click other navigation link ?

Comment: yes it does, what happens is, when i click a different navigation link something else should get displayed but now that happens and when i get back to the form link it does not display

Answer (score 0):

You've selected `$(".ps")` that means the form only shows when you click on the 'Program Sheet' link. If you want to toggle the form when click all other links just use `$("a")`.

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $("#div_data").slideToggle();
});
```

Also you've forgot to insert Jquery to your JSFiddle example. I'm not sure if it is the reason you are getting an issue.

Comment: no i only want to toggle the form when that link is clicked not all of them,

sorry, i will add it

Comment: Your JSFIddle example works fine for me. Try the `slideToggle()` function as I used above.

Comment: yes even your suggestion does work, the thing is on click of those other links i make ajax  requests when then display the data on the page, but when that data is displayed and i try to toggle the form it does not display on the page until i refresh.

Comment: i have add paragraph to my fiddle, just open the form then try to toggle the p tag and see how it responds, that is similar to what i am experiencing.

Comment: Can't see a paragraph in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hxjmxh4v/) fiddle. Still I'm not clear about the issue.

Comment: i must have forgotten to save it, the issue here is the form toggle only display if i only click on its toggle link, if i click a different link then click on the form toggle it does not display the form, i think its being display in the background.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aw23z87w/ check that one out, just toggle the paragraph, then the form and try to toggle the paragraph again you will see what im trying to explain